# Do I need a new client connection when using redis transactions?

Tags: redis, transactions, locking, watch, ioredis

My application uses a singleton connection of redis everywhere, it's initialized at the startup.
My understanding of `MULTI.EXEC()` tells that all my `WATCHed` keys would be `UNWATCHed` when the `MULTI.EXEC()` is called anywhere in the application.
This would mean that all keys `WATCHed` irrespective of which `MULTI` block they were `WATCHed` for will be unwatched, beating the whole purpose of `WATCHing` them.

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. How do I avoid this situation, should I create a new connection for each transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct. If you're using a singleton connection to Redis across your entire application and you're issuing WATCH commands on that connection, all keys watched on that connection will be unwatched when any MULTI/EXEC block is executed. So **you'll be needing a separate connection  to ensure that the WATCH command is clubbed with the only EXEC you want.**

**In an answer it is mentioned**
[image]
**I don't think it is right as the WATCH command in Redis operates on a per-connection basis.** When you issue a WATCH command, it applies only to the connection that issued the command.

When you issue a WATCH command for a specific key or keys, Redis marks those keys as "watched" within the context of the current connection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This process happened inside Redis Server and will block all incoming command. So it doesn't matter if you use single or multiple connections(all connections will be blocked)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607397/interleaving-watch-multi-exec-on-a-single-redis-connection-expected-or-weird-be
Suggests otherwise.
Can you please confirm this?