# Redis as LRU cache race condition

Tags: database, node.js, caching, redis

Imagine following scenario:

1. Client #1 requests object A from Redis
2. Redis answers with null
3. Client #1 requests object A from database
4. Database returns object A
5. Client #1 stores object A in Redis

Everything works fine. Let's add another client between 4 and 5:

1. Client #1 requests object A from Redis
2. Redis answers with null
3. Client #1 requests object A from database
4. Database returns object A

   - Client #2 requests object A from Redis
   - Redis answers with null
   - Client #2 requests object A from dtabase
   - Database returns object A
   - Client #2 stores object A in Redis
   - Client #2 updates object A, both in database and Redis
5. Client #1 stores object A in Redis

Now object A is up to date in database, but outdated in Redis. Are there any patterns to prevent such behaviour? Obviously locking the database while waiting for Redis to store its copy isn't a solution.

I should also note I'm using NodeJS which maintains a fixed size connection pool to Redis and requests are processed asynchronously, so we can't assume that the order of queries from different clients won't be mixed in a single connection.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are **not changed often (non-volatile)**, as in Historical data from yesterday or a month ago, you can safely ignore the race condition, because no matter who got the last commit, data is still the same across clients.

For **time sensitive** data, especially transaction data, you can separate the cache based on **user id** by using user id (Client#1, Client#2) as the additional Key. This will **eliminate race condition** between clients without resorting to locking and transaction synchronization with **drawback of higher memory usage**.

This method can be **combined** with the first method e.g. if the data is about user specific data, you can use user id key, and on the other hand if the data contains shared/grouping information like menu access based on role, you can use the group id instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Redis transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions).  The key is the `WATCH` command.  You call `WATCH` on object A before the initial read, and set the object inside a `MULTI`.  Now your two scenarios look like:

1. Client #1 WATCHes object A in Redis
2. Client #1 requests object A from Redis
3. Redis answers with null
4. Client #1 requests object A from database
5. Database returns object A
6. Client #1 stores object A in Redis in MULTI/EXEC block

and

1. Client #1 WATCHes object A in Redis
2. Client #1 requests object A from Redis
3. Redis answers with null
4. Client #1 requests object A from database
5. Database returns object A

   - Client #2 requests object A from Redis
   - Redis answers with null
   - Client #2 requests object A from dtabase
   - Database returns object A
   - Client #2 stores object A in Redis
   - Client #2 updates object A, both in database and Redis
6. Client #1 stores object A in Redis in MULTI/EXEC block, *but it fails because object A changed since the WATCH*

After failure, Client #1 could retry, but it's probably better to just ignore the failure, since it appears that you're just using it as a cache.

Client #2, of course, should have also done the WATCH/MULTI/EXEC pattern.

Comment: I'm afraid `watch` commands don't work with pooled connections and asynchronous processing in NodeJS. Commands from different clients are mixed together.

Comment: @SebastianNowak That's a problem with your library or usage, not Node.js.  I've used `watch`/`multi` in NodeJS just fine.  If you add details about your usage I'd be happy to show you how.

Comment: I'd have to create a new connection to Redis for every client in order to make `watch` work. This behaviour is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20186334/853906 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20216928/853906

Comment: @SebastianNowak Can you define "client" here?  I think I'm having trouble understanding exactly what's going on, because your statement doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not an update operation on object (5th step), you should use [SETNX](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) to store it. So you don't store outdated object.

Comment: There are multiple scenarios when it might fail. For example client #2 can remove the object completely and then client #1 will restore it in cache.

Comment: Why do you need to remove something from a cache storage?